# Microsoft Teams - Sharepoint list - Deep link to place call

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams, deep-linking

I have created a sharepoint list which contains contact information (name, phone number, ...). I have set conditional formatting on the column to include a phone icon with a hyperlink (deep link) to https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=4:%2B to call the phone number. So far so good ;-)

Condittional formatting applied to the column containing the phone number:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "padding-right": "8px"
      },
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    },
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "style": {
        "text-decoration": "none"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if(substring(@currentField,0,1) == '+','phone','')",
        "class": "sp-field-quickActions",
        "href": {
          "operator": "+",
          "operands": [
            "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=4:",
            "=replace(@currentField,'+','%2B')"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The SharePoint list is added as a tab in my Teams client and opening correctly showing all the entries but when I click the phone button the Teams client will show the "stay better connected with the Teams desktop app" window (see screenshot) instead off opening the pop-up box asking if it may call the number.

[image: Picture showing the SP List opened up as Teams TAB]

Picture showing Teams asking what client to use:
[image: Picture showing Teams asking what client to use.]

I also created a power automate flow which uses the same info to post an adaptive card to a user with a button to call the number and there everything works as expected with the same URL format.

Opening the SharePoint list as a webpage and clicking on the phone icon results in the Teams desktop client asking for permission to call the number but a webpage tab is kept open with the message "stay better connected with the Teams desktop app ..." (not clean)

Am I doing something wrong? Should this be working and have I stumbled on a bug?

Comment: It is Bydefault Behavior. 
Could you please help by suggesting this feature on https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472

Comment: I have posted the same info in the feedback portal. For other people that want to up vote please feel free: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/8f0b6a0a-8c23-ed11-a81b-6045bd7d68ae